# getting Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python37\python.exe" "C:\Python37\Scripts\pyrcc5.exe"

Tags: python

So i'm a beginner at machine learning and i want to try out this project i found it youtube ([link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOI0o3Cxv9Q&t=350s)) but the problem is when i get onto the step where i do `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc` in the command prompt it gives the error:

> Fatal error in launcher:
> Unable to create process using '"c:\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Python37\Scripts\pyrcc5.exe" -o resources.py resources.qrc'

which i don't understand why because i did everything the guy did in the video

Comment: maybe you don't have a `c:\python37`?  What is the code you ran to produce this?  Is it important that one is capitalised, the other not?

Comment: i re-downloaded python to the c drive but the python37 folder doesn't have python.exe for some reason how do i fix this?

Comment: I have no idea: you need to install python properly (use the standard installer) before you do anything else.  You still haven't said what caused the above error (I presume some handwritten launcher/shortcut?).  In any case the question is'how do I install python' and the answer is 'have a look at the website'.  I don't run windows, sadly, so I can't help much further

Comment: as for what caused the error i don't know as well i copied everything the guy did and double checked it before pressing enter

Comment: that's not what I mean: I don't know *what you did* and *where you pressed enter*.  Note that 'this worked for some guy in a video' does not imply 'this will work for me' unless absolutely nothing has changed between the two environments---which is very unlikely.  But in any case this is likely off topic here: you just need to install Python properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "System Environment Variables". There, check out Python & Python scripts path. Make sure those match your Python's path (that you are now in).

Comment: My answers here have some typo here and there. Yes Im not a natives

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).